# Routing in array Angular 5

Tags: arrays, string, angular, dynamic, routes

I have a string array of dynamic content that I need to add routing and HTML tags within for paragraphs and links. I can't seem to find the correct term for this kind of routing or usage of HTML. What am I missing?

Example-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-new',
 templateUrl: './new.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./new.component.css']
})
export class NewComponent implements OnInit  {
new: object[];

constructor(private router: Router) {


this.new =  [
    {
      newtitle: "This is my title",
      newcontent: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a (click)="newLink()">consectetuer</a> adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.<br>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat."
    }
]

}
```

Comment: Would you please clarify what you're wanting to accomplish exactly? Are you wanting to dynamically display HTML in your component template that contains routerLinks to the rest of your application? The limited code you have provided really doesn't help demonstrate what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I am working with large sections of dynamic text. Within much of the dynamic text are links, some internal and some external. The links currently work as long as they are directly typed into the component.html page, however, if they are within the array text they do not work.

Comment: You're going to need to use Dynamic Components. This article will get you started: https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e

Comment: Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to show the newcontent in new.component.html. Here is how you can do it:

in new.component.html:

```
<div [innerHtml]="new.newcontent | keepHtml: 'html'"></div>
```

Create a new pipe safe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Pipe({ name: 'keepHtml', pure: false })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}

public transform(value: string, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
switch (type) {
    case 'html':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    case 'style':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
    case 'script':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
    case 'url':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
    case 'resourceUrl':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
    default:
        throw new Error(`Unable to bypass security for invalid type: ${type}`);
}
}
}
```

Note: Don't forget to add the pipe to your app modules.

Comment: This worked great to be able to add line breaks and basic tags. I am still not able to get the link to work and classes don't work either?

Comment: @RyanIndustries8 Of course, this solution only applies for very basic and simple HTML. If your html has any level of complexity (such as router links) then you will be required to use Dynamic Components to create the necessary templates. If I had to guess, that is why it got down voted, because this solution does nothing for your use case.